# How shall I enter BIOS after Ubuntu has fully started?

Tags: bios, ubuntu-12.04

I would like to change some settings in BIOS.. How shall I enter the BIOS after Ubuntu has fully started?

BTW: I have been in the middle of working on something under Ubuntu for quite a few days. I don't want to restart it.

Comment: For *some* motherboards, there are tools that allow you to change *some* settings without a restart. Which motherboard do you have?

Comment: My laptop is Lenovo T400.

Comment: Note that even if you are able to change a bios setting, the chances are good that it won't take effect until the next boot anyway.  BIOS is responsible for bootstrapping your hardware and then handing off control to the boot loader which subsequently hands off control to the OS.  If you are trying to edit a bios setting because you don't want to reboot, you are out of luck unless your motherboard and Ubuntu drivers support making live changes to that particular hardware.  (For example, some OC motherboards support changing timings and voltages on the fly.)

Answer (score 8):

You can't "enter" your BIOS without rebooting. However, BIOS settings can be changed during runtime. It very much depends on the BIOS you are running. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259124/apis-for-querying-and-setting-bios-properties for more information.

Also, a lot of what you might want to change is exported to /proc and/or /sys and can be changed rather easily. A lot of all of this depends on the vendor of your motherboard. For Dell (just used as an example), there is libsmbios which already gives you the possibility of editing some bios settings.